# heapshot shows memory increase but give me nonsense backtrace

Tags: iphone, memory

Here is the screenshot of heapshot. Everytime I swipe to the next page in the app, I did mark heapshot in instrument:
[image]
There're many s of 304 bytes exists in memory and make memory increase. The detail pane shows backtrace nothing related to my code in app. Just many libCGFreetyp.A.dylib or other system framework and why is that.

Comment: Do you have a good memory management in your code? using ARC yet?

Comment: YES, I use ARC in xcode.

Comment: Can you show the code to us ? We need more detail on what the event the problem occured.

Comment: Even with ARC you can have memory issues...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure heapshot is the easiest way to go about solving this problem. Try using the Leak tool first and if that doesn't clearly indicate which object is being leaked, use Allocations and figure out which objects are allocated when you switch to the next page. From there, it's just a matter of following that object to determine at what point your reference should be removed.